# Send OSD notification messages to all systems on a network

Tags: mythtv, mythbuntu

What I'm trying to do is send caller ID (CID) information from a system running Asterisk+FreePBX to all (3) MythTV frontend systems on my network. I'd like the CID information to pop-up over top of whatever is going on (eg, whether it's on a menu, or playing back a recording). Eventually there may be other information as well, but for now CID would be a great start.

The libnotify-style notifications are fine (though I probably need to increase text size to make it visible). I was thinking something like [Growl](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Growl_%28software%29), though this doesn't seem to exist for Linux.

Ideally I'd just be able to do some kind of broadcast to the whole network, eg, from the FreePBX system I could run a command like:

```
notify --broadcast  --title "Incoming Call"  "Smith J\n613-555-1234"
```

And then on any mythtv frontend, it would appear somewhere on screen.

---

Note: there is a [MythNotify](http://www.mythtv.org/wiki/Setting_up_MythNotify) plugin, which I have used in a previous iteration of my setup, but it has a severe limitation (I believe based on the way MythTV's OSD stuff works) that it can only display notifications during video playback: not while in menus. I also remember it being a pain to get displaying properly: it uses XML for messaging then XSLT to change to mythtv's XML format. If you want to display something slightly differently, you have to make a small handful of new XML files and even then getting the "callerid-from-phonebook.xml" message to actually render to the (remote) "callerid-from-phonebook-osd.xml" file for display is some kind of black art.

Comment: Sounds like we need an OSD client to receive messages sent using `wall`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it by using the command-line notification tools.

1. Install the package 'libnotify-bin' on all of the systems on your network, which provides a tool called 'notify-send'.
2. Install the ssh server on all the systems on your network and make sure they are configured to allow passwordless ssh logins (see http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/152 for more information on this).
3. Set up your notification script on your server to execute notify-send, like this:

   ssh username@system1 'notify-send "Incoming call from Smith J\n613-555-1234"'

   ssh username@system2 'notify-send "Incoming call from Smith J\n613-555-1234"'

This will cause a notification popup on the systems named 'system1' and 'system2'.

Comment: I am sorry but your suggestion does not work, notify-send depends on the current session dbus, connecting via ssh will not setup the DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS variable to the proper address.

Comment: What I did was make a shell script on each system that did export DISPLAY=:0 (necessary to interact with X from ssh), then called notify-send (with some other params). On one of the systems, I even have that script wake up the screen first (its an LCD monitor, using dpms).